# HTML / CSS - input date height width

Tags: html, css

Como eu consigo alterar o `height` e `width` da tag `input` do tipo date e time, no próprio HTML ou no CSS ?

Comment: **fares** se você tiver uma nova pergunta, faça-a, não mude a pergunta atual, pois já existe resposta para a mesma. Estou revertendo sua edição.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vc pode selecionar o tipo do `input` que quer usando o `attr` do CSS direto para o tipo `date` e tipo `time` dessa forma.

Nesse exemplo além do `width` eu tb coloquei uma `bordar` para vc ver como só pega o estilo nos inputs com o tipo definido no `attr`

```css
input[type="date"], 
input[type="time"] {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<input type="date">
<input type="time">
<input type="text" placeholder="tipo text">
<input type="email" placeholder="tipo email">
```

Comment: Obrigado... deu certo. Queria saber agora como tiro a legenda, que não apareça "dd/mm/aaaa" e "-- : --".

Comment: @fares repare que isso vai mudar a classe de todos os inputs do tipo data e tempo, então vc pode encapsulalos dentro do seu form colocando uma classe pai tipo `form.contato input[type="date"] { }` isso vai fazer com que só os inputs desse tipo dentro do form com a classe contato peguem o css não todos os input date do seu site inteiro se for o caso de terem outros entende

Comment: Entendi... mas como consigo fazer?

Comment: Coloquei assim... mas não deu...                           input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
}

Comment: @fares o que acontece é que por algum motivo o browser só vai aceitar a classe se vc coloca-las separadas por tipos. Dessa forma "input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator { }" e o outro assim "input[type="time"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button { }" se vc colocar os dois tipos juntos só separado pela virgula o browser não reconhece não sei pq...

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode adicionar a tag style diretamente na sua tag html como por exemplo :

```
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" style="width:500px;height:500px;">
```

Porém não e recomendado e se eu não me engano não e uma boa prática.

Answer (score 1):

Usando `CSS`:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #date{width:500px;height:500px}
</style>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date">
```